# using unsetf with hex dec and octal numbers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a question about using [`unsetf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/unsetf). The below is an answer for getting correct input for formatted numbers.

> Actually, You can force `operator>>` to get and properly interpret
>   prefixes `0` and `0x`. All you have to do is to remove default settings
>   for `std::cin`:
>
> ```
> std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::dec);
> std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::hex);
> std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::oct);
> ```
>
> Now, when you input `0x1a` you will receive `26`.

I don't understand the last two `unsetf` commands for `hex` and `oct`. If I use the `unsetf` with `dec` only, I get the correct input, which I mean inputting `0x1a` and receiving `26`.

So what's the point of using `unsetf` for `hex` and `dec`?

Comment: Do you *know*, 100% really know, that the `hex` or `oct` flags haven't been set? Why not simply *make sure* they aren't set?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand the last two unsetf commands for hex and oct

**If** the `hex` and `oct` flags have not been set previously, yes unsetting `dec` is sufficient:

```
std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::dec);
int n;
std::cin >> n;  // 0x1a
std::cout << n; // 26
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8efb9833d5f9480d))

**But**, if those flags have been set previously, they might impact the parsing of your hex numbers:

```
std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::dec);    
int n;
std::cin >> n;  // 0x1a
std::cout << n; // 0
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd9cb6a4625cb2f))

So, if you want to let `std::cin` parse your number by guessing their base, you should `unsetf` `hex`, `dec` *and* `oct`.